# Ubuntu can not find python3, which is intalled

Tags: python3

I have Python installed on Ubuntu, as it appear when I execute on terminal:

$ python -V
Python 3.7.3

But some issues which depend on Python 3 are not working, I just cant execute Skype, Synaptic...

When I try to re-install Skype it returns the following error:

$ sudo apt install ./skypeforlinux-64.deb
...
E: Package python3 needs to be reinstalled, it was not possible to find such file.

I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: Python should refer to the current python2. Only python3 should refer to the current python3 version installed. Did you change links in /usr/bin.  What does this show? ` ls -l /usr/bin/python*`

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy python3` and `which python3`, `which python` to the question. What is your Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 2):

It says Package python3 needs to be reinstalled, so maybe a reinstall will solve the problem. To reinstall python3, please run:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3
```

After that try to install your packages.